# Scrolling div/section with indicators

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a vertical scrolling div with an active indicators. However I'm having trouble with it event firing on the div targeted. I set it to window.addEventListener it works fine at full height of the window but if I set it to div.addEventListener it's not firing inside of the element at all. I'm Hoping someone has some pointer for this. Here's what I got so far.

```
section.scroller {
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: auto;
    background: antiquewhite;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-right: 17px;
    // padding: 0 17px;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

.sec {
    min-height: 100vh;
    // width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    // width: 100%;
    &:nth-child(odd) {
        background: #ddd;
    }
}

.lnbNavbar {
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 15px;
    transition: opacity .4s ease .2s;
    opacity: 0;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    transition: .3s all;
    ul {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        li {
            width: 0px;
            position: relative;
            text-align: right;
            .dot {
                border: 2px solid#333;
                width: 10px;
                height: 10px;
                display: inline-block;
                border-radius: 50%;
                transition: .2s ease;
                span {
                    display: inline-block;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

.lnbNavbar ul li a:active,
.lnbNavbar ul li a:hover {
    border-color: rgb(124, 7, 7);
    background-color: gray;
    transform: scale(1.8);
}

.lnbNavbar ul li.active a,
.lnbNavbar ul li:hover a {
    border-color: rgb(124, 7, 7);
    background-color: gray;
    transform: scale(1.8);
}

.outter {
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}







<div class="outter" id="outter">
<section class="scroller" id="scroller">
<nav class="lnbNavbar">
    <ul>
        <li class="home active">
            <a href="#home" class=" home dot">
                <span></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="about">
            <a href="#about" class="about dot">
                <span></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="service">
            <a href="#service" class="service dot">
                <span></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="project">
            <a href="#project" class="project dot">
                <span></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="contact">
            <a href="#contact" class="contact dot">
                <span></span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<section class="sec" id="about"><h4>about</h4></section>
<section class="sec" id="service"><h4>service</h4></section>
<section class="sec" id="project"><h4>project</h4></section>
<section class="sec" id="contact"><h4>contact</h4></section>
<section class="sec" id="home"><h4>home</h4></section>
</section>

<script>
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
const navLi = document.querySelectorAll('.lnbNavbar ul li');
const div = document.getElementById("outter")[0];


div.addEventListener('scroll', ()=> {
    let current = '';
    sections.forEach( section => {
        const sectionTop = section.offsetTop;
        const sectionHeight = section.clientHeight;
        if(pageYOffset >= (sectionTop - sectionHeight / 4)){
            current = section.getAttribute('id');
        }
    })

    console.log(current);
    navLi.forEach( li => {
        li.classList.remove('active');
        if(li.classList.contains(current)){
            li.classList.add('active')
        }
    })
})
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `.` be a `:` in `.lnbNavbar ul li.active a,`?

Comment: Since ids are unique, `getElementById` only returns one element : `div = document.getElementById("outter")[0];` ==> `div = document.getElementById("outter");`